# Check if value already exists in dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a UI which gets populated from user selections. The key of my dictionary is just a simple string, but it may correspond to multiple string entries (the List).

If the user makes different selections, I should be able to go through this dictionary,**and for the same string key, check whether a string from the selections that the user just made in my List already exists, and if it does, not add it**. If it doesn't exist, then add to the already existing list.

I started with the following code:

```
var checkedItems = listViewColumns.CheckedItems;
if (checkedItems != null)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
    {
        if ((m_ColumnAssociations.ContainsKey(item.Text)) 
        {
            var correspondingMatrices = m_ColumnAssociations.Where(kvp =>
                kvp.Value.Contains(dgvMatrices.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString())).
                Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

where `listViewColumns` is a listview containing the entries that go into the dictionary keys, and `m_ColumnAssociations` is my dictionary. I am adding entries elsewhere to my code, so this part is sorted. My questions is on the checking which is being done here.

In my current attempt I am trying only to get a value for now (`correspondingMatrices`) but this statement returns me an IEnumerable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking to get the value you should get the first record that it finds using FirstOrDefault(): 
var correspondingMatrices = m_ColumnAssociations.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(dgvMatrices.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString())).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).FirstOrDefault();

Then you can get the values from that.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<String>>` instead? Btw, do you also want to remove items which don't exist anymore?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes I can use a hashset. I would also like to remove items, that the user has selected for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you need something the following:

```
var checkedItems = listViewColumns.CheckedItems;
if (checkedItems != null)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
    {
        List<string> itemsForAdding = // some items that needs to be added

        // check if dictionary has the key
        if (m_ColumnAssociations.ContainsKey(item.Text)) 
        {
            var listFromDictionary = m_ColumnAssociations[item.Text];

            foreach(var itemForAdding in itemsForAdding)
            {
                if(!listFromDictionary.Contains(itemForAdding)
                {
                    listFromDictionary.Add(itemForAdding);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use `Distinct` method:

```
...
List<string> itemsForAdding = // some items that needs to be added

// check if dictionary has the key
if (m_ColumnAssociations.ContainsKey(item.Text)) 
{
    var listFromDictionary = m_ColumnAssociations[item.Text];

    // add the whole list
    listFromDictionary.AddRange(itemsForAdding);

    // remove the duplicates from the list and save it back to dictionary
    m_ColumnAssociations[item.Text] = listFromDictionary.Distinct();
}
...
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was as simple as doing this: var listFromDictionary = m_ColumnAssociations[item.Text]; and then checking that list.

Comment: Also, two performance suggestions: 1) `TryGetValue` is a bit cheaper than `ContainsKey` + indexed access (single operation), 2) `Distinct` creates a hashtable instance internally to keep track of yielded items, so it would be better if OP had a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` (although OPs code doesn't have anything related to this part of your example, so I am not sure why you included it).